# Logstash Filter - Convert key name from "this_is_example" => 1 to [this][is][example] => 1

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

Given this LogStash event, a ruby hash

```
{
    "_some_private_key" => 10,
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => 1098,
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK",
    "apartment_floor_unit_door" => "5",
    "tags" => [
        "pub",
        "importer",
        "assessment"
    ]
}
```

That should be stored into ES as

```
{
  "_some_private_key": 10,
  "address": {
    "unit": 1,
    "sqft": 1098,
    "city": "NEW YORK"
  },
  "apartment": {
    "floor" : {
      "unit": {
        doors: 1043
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": [
    "pub",
    "importer",
    "assessment"
  ]
}
```

Constraints:

- Should bypass keys starting with `_`
- Should be dynamic/recursive, check the key `apartment_floor_unit_door` example

I would like to know if there's some built-in/community filter to achieve it, or how to achieve it using ruby code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to mudasobwas answer but using `each_with_object` instead. I prefer this method over `inject` whenever possible (each_with_object only works with mutable objects because you do not return a new object at the end of the block)

```
def convert(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), akku|
    if (parts = key.split('_')).length == 2
      akku[parts[0]] ||= {}
      akku[parts[0]][parts[1]] = value
    else
      akku[key] = value
    end
  end
end
```

Also I did not use Regexp (only indirectly via `.split()`) because I think this is more readable).

Do you need to deal with keys with multiple underscores? Or more levels of nesting?

UPDATE:

```
def convert(input)
  input.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), output|
    next if key.start_with?('_')
    keys = key.split('_')
    convert_keys(output, keys, value)
  end
end

def convert_keys(output, keys, value)
  keys[0...-1].each do |key|
    output = output[key] ||= {}
  end
  output[keys.last] = value
end
```

This should do the trick. It is not recursive (does not work if a value of the input hash is again a hash with keys that need to be broken down) because your sample input did not require that. The `convert_keys` method could be done recursively as well. But i prefer the iterative approach here.

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Pascal, thanks for your answer! I failed to specify that it need to be dynamic. I updated the question with more information, including constraints. Your code is almost there, it just need to be dynamic/recursive. Can you still help? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot! Please continue like this, SO need people like you to understand what's means help each other. SO today is about a bunch of people that have knowledge, and when people go there and ask for help, the best they can do is say: Search in Google and learn in 30 minutes it, BULLSHIT! Cheers man, you rock and saved my a**! Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = {
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => 1098,
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK",
    "tags" => ["pub", "importer", "assessment"]
}

inp.inject({}) do |memo, (k, v)| 
  if k =~ /\A(.*?)_(.*)/
    (memo[$~[1]] ||= {})[$~[2]] = v
  else
    memo[k] = v
  end
  memo
end 

#⇒ {
#  "address" => {
#     "city" => "NEW YORK",
#     "sqft" => 1098,
#     "unit" => "1"
#   },
#     "tags" => [
#    [0] "pub",
#    [1] "importer",
#    [2] "assessment"
#  ]
# }
```

The code above will break all underscored `foo_bar` keys into nested ones.

Comment: Hi! It's almost there! I updated the question adding the constraints. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You misunderstand how SO works. Nobody will just write a code for you.

Comment: I don't  misunderstand how SO works, is people like you that's destroying SO, also know that deleting my old comment will not change it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example (three fields), how about a logstash solution:

```
mutate {
    rename => { "address_unit" => "[address][unit]" }
    rename => { "address_sqft" => "[address][sqft]" }
    rename => { "address_city" => "[address][city]" }
}
```

I didn't look to see if rename can do multiple in one shot, so you might try that, too.

Comment: Sorry, but it's need to be dynamic. I updated the question to reflect the real needs. Thanks!